# Block passed to deallocator for newBufferWithBytesNoCopy is never called/used

Tags: objective-c, macos, memory-leaks, metal, mtlbuffer

I have the following inside the `main` function. I have ensured earlier that `CONTENT_SIZE` is page aligned.

```
if (!(Queue = [Device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice() newCommandQueue])) // Set global variables
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
{
    const id<MTLBuffer> data = [Device newBufferWithBytesNoCopy:({
        void *const map = ({
            NSFileHandle *const file = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:[NSBundle.mainBundle pathForResource:@"Content" ofType:nil]];
            if (!file)
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            mmap(NULL, CONTENT_SIZE, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, file.fileDescriptor, 0);
        });
        if (map == MAP_FAILED)
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        map;
    }) length:CONTENT_SIZE options:MTLResourceStorageModeShared deallocator:^(void *const ptr, const NSUInteger len){

        munmap(ptr, len); // Never called

    }];
    if (!data)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    const id<MTLCommandBuffer> buffer = [Queue commandBuffer];
    const id<MTLBlitCommandEncoder> encoder = [buffer blitCommandEncoder];
    if (!encoder)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    // Below, the contents of buffer are copied to MTLTexture

    MTLTextureDescriptor *const descriptor = [MTLTextureDescriptor new];
    descriptor.width = descriptor.height = 32;
    descriptor.mipmapLevelCount = 6;
    descriptor.textureType = MTLTextureType2DArray;
    descriptor.storageMode = MTLStorageModePrivate;
    const enum MTLPixelFormat format[] = {MTLPixelFormatR8Unorm, MTLPixelFormatRG8Unorm, MTLPixelFormatRGBA8Unorm};
    const NSUInteger len[] = {TEX_LEN_1, TEX_LEN_2, TEX_LEN_4};
    for (NSUInteger i = 3, off = 0; i--;) {
        descriptor.pixelFormat = format[i];
        const NSUInteger l = descriptor.arrayLength = len[i];
        const id<MTLTexture> texture = [Device newTextureWithDescriptor:descriptor];
        if (!texture)
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        const NSUInteger br = 32<<i, bi = 1024<<i;
        for (NSUInteger j = 0; j < l; off += bi)
            [encoder copyFromBuffer:data sourceOffset:off sourceBytesPerRow:br sourceBytesPerImage:bi sourceSize:(const MTLSize){32, 32, 1} toTexture:texture destinationSlice:j++ destinationLevel:0 destinationOrigin:(const MTLOrigin){0}];
        [encoder generateMipmapsForTexture:BlockTexture[i] = texture]; // BlockTexture is a global variable
    }

    [encoder endEncoding];
    [buffer commit];
}
```

But I noticed that the block passed for `deallocator:` is never called. I can put `puts()`, `abort()`, whatever in there, and nothing happens. This means no deallocation is taking place, even long after the data has been copied to the textures and is no longer needed and the reference to the buffer goes out of scope.

I view this as a memory leak. How can I ensure that the `mmap()`ed memory is properly `munmap()`ed after the buffer is no longer needed?

Comment: Try to put `@autoreleasepool` around the insides of the `if` and see if that helps.

Comment: What's happening is that the `MTLBuffer` probably never goes out of scope, this can happen for a couple reasons: one is autorelease pool, the other is validation or capture layer may retain the buffer longer than you expect. Try adding the autoreleasepool, and also try running without validation and capture enabled and see if that still reproduces.

Comment: @JustSomeGuy Adding `@autoreleasepool` to the block after the `if` worked.

Comment: That means that buffer was getting added to global autorelease pool. That pool will only get drained at the end of `main` basically

Comment: @JustSomeGuy And once `main()` returns, the program is ended, so it never gets drained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the code in the `main()` function, and no `@autoreleasepool`, the object is never released because there is no pool that drains before the program terminates. This causes the deallocator to never be called.

The solution is to enclose all relevant code inside the `main()` function in an `@autoreleasepool { }` block, as originally suggested in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74424261/block-passed-to-deallocator-for-newbufferwithbytesnocopy-is-never-called-used#comment131403803_74424261).